# Согласование подлежащего и сказуемого.

Tags: падежи

Не могу убедить оппонента, что слово ТОТ в предложении: "Тот, кто отвечал Вам по Интернету о возможных или невозможных, на его взгляд, сочетаниях при случае передайте от меня несколько сочетаний: ..." должно быть употреблено в дательном падеже: ТОМУ.
Да и запятая перед предлогом ПРИ не помешала бы.
Пособите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

"Тому, кто отвечал..." и далее по тексту. Вопрос: "Кому передать от меня несколько сочетаний?" После "сочетаниях", конечно, нужна занятая

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с русаком. Единственное, что я могу добавить, - это то, что ни о каком согласовании подлежащего и сказуемого в Вашем вопросе речь не идет. Вопрос сводится к выбору падежной формы дополнения.

Answer (score 0):

Если оставить, как было, то непонятно: что делает ТОТ и какой вопрос и к какому слову надо задать от слова "передайте".

Comment: Уважаемая Злата! Ваша, как впрочем и "предыдущих ораторов", лаконичность не убедила моего оппонента: он по-прежнему считает, что вправе выбирать падежные окончания как в голову взбредет. Разверните, прошу, свое разъяснение, чтобы даже ребенку, завзятому двоечнику, стало понятно. Весьма обяжете.

Answer (score 0):

"Тот, кто отвечал Вам по Интернету о возможных или невозможных, на его взгляд, сочетаниях при случае передайте от меня несколько сочетаний: ..."
Я думаю, что Вы, legkruk, правильно рассуждаете. Попробую "развернуть" объяснение, чтоб и ребёнку было понятно...
Дело в том, что это СПП, состоящее из главного "Тому... при случае передайте от меня и  далее по тексту..." и придаточного "кто отвечал по Интернету о возможных или невозможных, на его взгляд, сочетаниях". В каждом из них есть своя грамматическая основа: в первом - передайте, во втором - кто отвечал. Придаточное находится внутри главного (такая своеобразная "матрёшка"), оно выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.
Поэтому права Noir, когда говорит, что от сказуемого "передайте" следует поставить вопрос к дополнению: передайте (КОМУ?) - ТОМУ.